# Async Import Data Azure Blob

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm trying to import data that is delimited into my Azure storage. The example of the data is:
email:lastpurchasedate

The data file sizes are up to 2-5gb of size. I'm using the below code to validate the email data first, batch them, then import. Please ignore any syntax error I've changed it slightly on here.

At the moment it works fine if I have nothing under foreach line it reads perfectly no memory issues. The moment I add my validation code, I get memory exceptions. however, I'm clearing the batches once submitted. Here is where the error is thrown:
[Error][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGA17.png

**Full Attempt**

```
public static async void readData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the file location: ");
        var fileName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Now reading: " + fileName);
        Console.WriteLine("Logging to: " + logfilename);
        var totalRead = 0;

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------
        string prvdomainName = "";
        string mail = "placeholder@mail.com";
        string lastpurchdt= "12345";
        int firstRun = 0;
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------
        var batchBlock = new BatchBlock<string>(batchSize: 500);
        var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<string[]>(batch =>
        {
            // Do something with the batch. For example:
            // Console.WriteLine("Processing batch");

            foreach (var line in batch)
            {
                totalProcessed = totalProcessed + 1;
                //Splits the line into usermail and lastpurchasedate
                char[] chDelimiter = { ':' };
                var pieces = line.Split(chDelimiter, 2);

                try
                {
                    mail = pieces[0];
                    pdate= pieces[1];

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    errordata = errordata + 1;
                    Log("Error: " + line);
                    continue;
                }

                if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(mail) == false) || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pdate) == false))
                {
                    //Regex validates that the email is an correct address based on regex
                    try
                    {
                        if (Regex.IsMatch(mail, validationRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)))
                        {

                            //Splits usermail into parts Partitionkey = domain, Rowkey = username
                            char[] chDelimiterN = { '@' };
                            var piecesN = mail.Split(chDelimiterN, 2);
                            string domainName = piecesN[1];
                            domainName = domainName.ToLower();
                            string userName = piecesN[0];
                            //Console.WriteLine("[*] --- Tender: " + line);
                            if (batcha.Count >= 100)
                            {

                                addData(batcha);
                                batcha.Clear();
                                batchCount = 1;
                            }

                            //If email validates then lets check if first record, if so let's start.
                            if ((firstRun <= 0) && (batcha.Count <= 100))
                            {

                               // Console.WriteLine("[*] --- First run: " + line);
                                var recordAccount = new recordAccount
                                {
                                    PartitionKey = domainName,
                                    RowKey = userName,
                                    purchDate = pdate
                                };
                                //Add the account to the batch for processing
                                batcha.InsertOrReplace(recordAccount);                      
                                prvdomainName = domainName;
                                userNames.Add(userName);
                                firstRun = 1;
                                totalUploaded = totalUploaded + 1;


                            }
                            //If email validates and there is a duplicate username...... and the batchcount fits our < 100 demands
                            else if ((userNames.Any(e => e.EndsWith(userName))) && (batcha.Count <= 100))
                            {
                                // MessageBox.Show("New batch user duplicated");
                                //new batch so lets first submit old one and clear the batches.
                                //Console.WriteLine("[*] --- Dup username: " + line);
                                addData(batcha);
                                batcha.Clear();
                                var recordAccount = new recordAccount
                                {
                                    PartitionKey = domainName,
                                    RowKey = userName,
                                    purchDate = pdate
                                };
                                //Add the account to the batch for processing
                                batcha.InsertOrReplace(recordAccount);                          
                                prvdomainName = domainName;
                                //  addData(batch);
                                totalUploaded = totalUploaded + 1;

                            }
                            //If email validates then lets check if current domain still same as old and the batchcount fits our < 100 demands
                            else if ((prvdomainName == domainName) && (batcha.Count <= 100))
                            {

                               // Console.WriteLine("[*] --- Normal same dom: " + line);


                                var recordAccount = new recordAccount
                                {
                                    PartitionKey = domainName,
                                    RowKey = userName,
                                    purchDate = pdate
                                };
                                //Add the account to the batch for processing
                                batcha.InsertOrReplace(recordAccount);
                                batchCount = batchCount + 1;
                                prvdomainName = domainName;
                                userNames.Add(userName);
                                totalUploaded = totalUploaded + 1;


                            }
                            //If email validates and there is a new domain name...... and the batchcount fits our < 100 demands
                            else if ((prvdomainName != domainName) && (batcha.Count <= 100))
                            {
                              //  Console.WriteLine("[*] --- New dom: " + line);

                                //  MessageBox.Show("New batch");
                                //new batch so lets first submit old one and clear the batches.
                                //  batchCount = 1;

                                addData(batcha);
                                batcha.Clear();
                                var recordAccount = new recordAccount
                                {
                                    PartitionKey = domainName,
                                    RowKey = userName,
                                    purchDate = pdate
                                };
                                //Add the account to the batch for processing
                                batcha.InsertOrReplace(recordAccount);
                                //  batchCount = batchCount + 1;
                                prvdomainName = domainName;
                                userNames.Add(userName);
                                totalUploaded = totalUploaded + 1;

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // txtOutput.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "Incorrect email: " + mail + Environment.NewLine);
                            Log("Mail Fail: " + line);
                            errordata = errordata + 1;
                            continue;
                        }

                    }
                    catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException)
                    {

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Log("Validaion Fail: " + line);
                    errordata = errordata + 1;
                    continue;
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine(totalProcessed);
       
        });
        batchBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(fileName))
        {
            await batchBlock.SendAsync(line).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        batchBlock.Complete();

        await actionBlock.Completion.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }


    public static void addData(TableBatchOperation batch)
    {
        var connString = "XXXXX";
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connString);
        var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        //Add the batch
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("XXXXXX");


        try
        {
            table.ExecuteBatch(batch);
            //batcha.Clear();
            batch.Clear();
            // batchCount = 1;
            userNames.Clear();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
               
                Log(ex.ToString());

            }

        Console.WriteLine("[+] --- Uploaded: " + totalUploaded);
        Console.WriteLine("[=] --- Total processed: " + totalProcessed);
        Console.WriteLine("[x] --- Error data: " + errordata);
        Log("Uploaded: " + totalUploaded);
        Log("Total Processed: " + totalProcessed);



    }
```

**Simplified code**

```
        var batchBlock = new BatchBlock<string>(batchSize: 50);
        var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<string[]>(batch =>
        {
            // Do something with the    batch. For example:
            // Console.WriteLine("Processing batch");      
            Console.WriteLine(batchBlock.BatchSize.ToString());
            foreach (var line in batch)
            {
                totalProcessed = totalProcessed + 1;
               

            }
            Console.WriteLine(totalProcessed);

        }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            BoundedCapacity = 2
        });
        batchBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(fileName))
        {
            await batchBlock.SendAsync(line).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        batchBlock.Complete();
        await actionBlock.Completion.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Exception details:

```
    Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.MultiBufferMemoryStream.AddBlock() in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\dotnet-nov17\Lib\Common\Core\MultiBufferMemoryStream.cs:line 646
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.MultiBufferMemoryStream.Reserve(Int64 requiredSize) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\dotnet-nov17\Lib\Common\Core\MultiBufferMemoryStream.cs:line 637
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.MultiBufferMemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\dotnet-nov17\Lib\Common\Core\MultiBufferMemoryStream.cs:line 299
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.NonCloseableStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\dotnet-nov17\Lib\Common\Core\NonCloseableStream.cs:line 171
at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.Protocol.TableOperationHttpWebRequestFactory.BuildRequestForTableBatchOperation(Uri uri, UriQueryBuilder builder, IBufferManager bufferManager, Nullable`1 timeout, String tableName, TableBatchOperation batch, Boolean useVersionHeader, OperationContext ctx, TableRequestOptions options) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\dotnet-nov17\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Table\Protocol\TableOperationHttpRequestFactory.cs:line 325
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableBatchOperation.<>c__DisplayClassa.<BatchImpl>b__6(Uri uri, UriQueryBuilder builder, Nullable`1 timeout, Boolean useVersionHeader, OperationContext ctx) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\dotnet-nov17\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Table\TableBatchOperation.cs:line 141
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ProcessStartOfRequest[T](ExecutionState`1 executionState, String startLogMessage) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\dotnet-nov17\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 849
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\dotnet-nov17\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 619
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\dotnet-nov17\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 632
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableBatchOperation.Execute(CloudTableClient client, CloudTable table, TableRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\dotnet-nov17\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Table\TableBatchOperation.cs:line 93
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.ExecuteBatch(TableBatchOperation batch, TableRequestOptions requestOption
```

Comment: What memory exceptions and what is their stack trace? Why are you using unboundade `BatchBlock` and `ActionBlock`?

Comment: The exception is out of memory. The batchblock code is from another stackoverflow which suited my scenario. Would running boundable solve my issue?

Comment: Exceptions, have stack traces that tell us where they were thrown. If you don't know why you're using things, don't use them. Instead of `BatchBlock` you should be setting limits to the `ActionBlock`.

Comment: There are several performance issues with your code. You are using an overload of `string.Split` that takes a `char[]` and creating a new array on every use instead of reusing a unique instance.

Comment: I've added image of where the error is thrown. Okay do you care to give an example on setting the limits?

Comment: I've added simplified version of the code with the Actionblock boundable. Still receiving memory issues.

Comment: You're still not showing the exception. Exception details are important to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to drop the `BatchBlock` and use just the `ActionBlock` and try different values for [MaxDegreeOfParallelism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions.maxdegreeofparallelism)?

Comment: Added the exception details for you.Thank you so much for your time to assist me.